# Find difference between two json files in python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have two json files as given below. And I want to find the difference between the two and write the differences to third json file.
I am expecting json diff should be calculated- (B.json-A.json)

A.json

```
  [{
        "Number": 123,
        "brand": "Ford",
        "model": {
            "Mustang1": "2.64",
            "Mustang2": "3.00",
            "Mustang3": "1.00",
            "Mustang4": "1.64"
        }
    },
    {
        "Number": 321,
        "brand": "Toyota",
        "model": {
            "Camry": "2.64",
            "Prius": "3.00",
            "Corolla": "1.00",
            "Tundra": "1.64"
        }
    },
    {
        "Number": 111,
        "brand": "Honda",
        "model": {
            "Accord": "2.64",
            "Civic": "3.00",
            "Insight": "1.00",
            "Pilot": "1.64"
        }
    },
    {
        "Number": 891,
        "brand": "Ford",
        "model": {
            "Mustang1": "2.64",
            "Mustang8": "3.00",
            "Mustang3": "1.00",
            "Mustang6": "1.64"
        }
    },
    {
        "Number": 745,
        "brand": "Toyota",
        "model": {
            "Camry": "2.64",
            "Sienna": "3.00",
            "4Runner": "1.00",
            "Prius": "1.64"
        }
    },
    {
        "Number": 325,
        "brand": "Honda",
        "model": {
            "Accord": "2.64",
            "Passport": "3.00",
            "HR-V": "1.00",
            "Pilot": "1.64"
        }
    },
    {
        "Number": 745,
        "brand": "Accura",
        "model": {
            "TLX": "2.64",
            "MDX": "3.00"
        }
    },
    {
        "Number": 325,
        "brand": "Accura",
        "model": {
            "TLX": "2.64",
            "MDX": "3.00"
        }
    }
]
```

B.json

```
        [{
        "Number": 123,
        "brand": "Ford",
        "model": {
            "Mustang1": "2.64",
            "Mustang2": "3.00",
            "Mustang5": "1.64"
        }
    },
    {
        "Number": 321,
        "brand": "Toyota",
        "model": {
            "Camry": "2.64",
            "Prius1": "3.00",
            "Corolla1": "1.00",
            "Tundra": "1.64"
        }
    },
    {
        "Number": 111,
        "brand": "Honda",
        "model": {
            "Accord1": "2.64",
            "Civic1": "3.00",
            "Insight": "1.00",
            "Pilot": "1.64"
        }
    },
    {
        "Number": 891,
        "brand": "Ford",
        "model": {
            "Mustang1": "2.64",
            "Mustang8": "3.00",
            "Mustang3": "1.00",
            "Mustang6": "1.64"
        }
    },
    {
        "Number": 745,
        "brand": "Toyota",
        "model": {
            "Camry2": "2.64",
            "Sienna2": "3.00",
            "4Runner": "1.00",
            "Prius": "1.64"
        }
    },
    {
        "Number": 325,
        "brand": "Honda",
        "model": {
            "Accord": "2.64",
            "Passport2": "3.00",
            "HR-V2": "1.00",
            "Pilot": "1.64"
        }
    },
    {
        "Number": 745,
        "brand": "Accura",
        "model": {
            "TLX": "2.64",
            "MDX2": "3.00"
        }
    },
    {
        "Number": 325,
        "brand": "Accura",
        "model": {
            "TLX1": "2.64",
            "MDX": "3.00"
        }
    }
]
```

This prints:

```
{0: {'model': {'$delete': ['Mustang3', 'Mustang4'],
               'Mustang2': '1.00',
               'Mustang5': '1.64'}},
 1: {'model': {'$delete': ['Prius', 'Corolla'],
               'Corolla1': '1.00',
               'Prius1': '3.00'}},
 2: {'model': {'$delete': ['Accord', 'Civic'],
               'Accord1': '2.64',
               'Civic1': '3.00'}},
 4: {'model': {'$delete': ['Camry', 'Sienna'],
               'Camry2': '2.64',
               'Sienna2': '3.00'}},
 5: {'model': {'$delete': ['Passport', 'HR-V'],
               'HR-V2': '1.00',
               'Passport2': '3.00'}},
 6: {'model': {'$delete': ['MDX'], 'MDX2': '3.00'}},
 7: {'model': {'$delete': ['TLX'], 'TLX1': '2.64'}}}
```

**Expected result**: is calculated based on B.json-A.json. It will check what all keys were there in model in A.json but not present in B.json - grouped by other keys- Number, brand.

```
{"Number": 123, "brand": "Ford", 'model': {'Mustang2': '1.00', 'Mustang5': '1.64'}},
{"Number": 321, "brand": "Toyota", 'model': {'Corolla1': '1.00', 'Prius1': '3.00'}},
{"Number": 111, "brand": "Honda", 'model': {'Accord1': '2.64', 'Civic1': '3.00'}},
{"Number": 745, "brand": "Toyota", 'model': {'Camry2': '2.64', 'Sienna2': '3.00'}},
{"Number": 325, "brand": "Honda", 'model': {'HR-V2': '1.00', 'Passport2': '3.00'}},
{"Number": 745, "brand": "Accura", 'model': {'MDX2': '3.00'}},
{"Number": 325, "brand": "Accura", 'model': {'TLX1': '2.64'}}}
```

Comment: Yes, A.json and B.json - are valid json files.

Comment: You can use [https://jsonlint.com/](https://jsonlint.com/) to check this.

Comment: @interjay Obviously these are "json-per-line" files.

Comment: Both a_li and b_li contain the same json object! Perhaps you need to edit your question @user15051990

Comment: yes looks like Mustang 2 was meant to be Mustang 3 in B.json

Comment: I don't understand your "expected result". What happens if those files have the same key but with different value? Also your diff doesn't say which one has what. The output doesn't look really valuable.

Comment: Sorry, I pasted the wrong json files. Now, I have edited my question. Can you guys please have a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`jsondiff`](https://github.com/xlwings/jsondiff) doesn't do what you (probably) are trying to.
If `A` and `B` lists have not necessarily same `Number` and `brand`:

```
res = []
for b in B:
    r = dict(b)
    b_in_A = next((a for a in A if b["Number"] == a["Number"] and b["brand"] == a["brand"]), None)
    if b_in_A:
        r["model"] = {k: v for k, v in r["model"].items() if k not in b_in_A["model"]}
    res.append(r)
res
```

Output:

```
[{'Number': 123, 'brand': 'Ford', 'model': {'Mustang5': '1.64'}},
 {'Number': 321,
  'brand': 'Toyota',
  'model': {'Corolla1': '1.00', 'Prius1': '3.00'}},
 {'Number': 111,
  'brand': 'Honda',
  'model': {'Accord1': '2.64', 'Civic1': '3.00'}},
 {'Number': 891, 'brand': 'Ford', 'model': {}},
 {'Number': 745,
  'brand': 'Toyota',
  'model': {'Camry2': '2.64', 'Sienna2': '3.00'}},
 {'Number': 325,
  'brand': 'Honda',
  'model': {'HR-V2': '1.00', 'Passport2': '3.00'}},
 {'Number': 745, 'brand': 'Accura', 'model': {'MDX2': '3.00'}},
 {'Number': 325, 'brand': 'Accura', 'model': {'TLX1': '2.64'}}]
```

Comment: I am getting error `    r = dict(b)`
`ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required`. When I am running this code: `A = open(path1)`
`B = open(path2)`
`res = []`

`for b in B:`
 `   r = dict(b)`
    `b_in_A = next((a for a in A if b["Number"] == a["Number"] and b["brand"] == `a["brand"]), None)`
    if b_in_A:
        r["model"] = {k: v for k, v in r["model"].items() if k not in b_in_A["model"]}
    res.append(r)`

Comment: I can just guess. in my code `A` and `B` are lists of dictionaries, while your `A` and `B` are `TextwIOWrapper` (`dict` is parsing a string in your code). use `import json` module and do `A = json.load(open(path1))` instead

Comment: I used `A = json.load(open(path1))` And now I am getting `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 2 column 1 (char 119)`

Comment: this probably means your file is not a well formatted json. Post an example of your file

Comment: Updated, Checkout B.json.

Comment: just copy-pasted B.json in a file and parsed, works perfectly. Try to do the same, check again your code. Can't do more than this, I'm sorry

Comment: Did you use `A = json.load(open(path1))`, 
`B = json.load(open(path2))`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192927/discussion-between-lante-dellarovere-and-user15051990).

Answer (score 0):

jsondiff appears to just compare to individual json objects to find differences in their keys. You appear to be trying to just get a list of json objects not in both lists. This could just be done by looping through and checking to see if the object is in both lists:

```
unique_cars = [car for car in jf if car not in jg]
for car in jg:
    if car not in jf:
        unique_cars.append(car)
```

There's likely a stdlib that handles this sort of thing. But that's the logic you want.

Comment: I am trying to get keys present in B.json (model) but not in A.json. And this should be grouped with `Number` and `brand`.